# Redux dispatch not properly updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am having an issue with my Redux reducer not properly updating state.

Here are my actions in my `accountActions.js` file.

```
// Get all accounts for specific user
export const getAccounts = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setAccountsLoading); // NOT WORKING
  axios
    .get("/api/plaid/accounts")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ACCOUNTS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ACCOUNTS,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};

// Accounts loading
export const setAccountsLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: ACCOUNTS_LOADING
  };
};
```

Here is my `actionsReducers.js` file.

```
import {
  GET_ACCOUNTS,
  ACCOUNTS_LOADING,
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  accounts: [],
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACCOUNTS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_ACCOUNTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        accounts: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The `dispatch(setAccountsLoading)` in my `getAccounts` action is not properly updating the `loading` state.

In my `Dashboard.js` component, I call `getAccounts`. Based on the `loading` state, I wish to display a "loading..." message. If there are zero accounts returned from `getAccounts`, I wish to display a message to add the first account. Otherwise, if `getAccounts` returns more one or more account, I wish to display the dashboard.

Here is my `Dashboard.js` component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PlaidLink from "react-plaid-link";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logoutUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import {
  getAccounts,
  addAccount
} from "../../actions/accountActions";

import Transactions from "./Transactions";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAccounts();
  }

  // Logout
  onLogoutClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser();
  };

  // Add account
  handleOnSuccess = (token, metadata) => {
    const plaidData = {
      public_token: token,
      metadata: metadata
    };

    this.props.addAccount(plaidData);
  };

  render() {
    const { accounts, loading } = this.props.plaid;

    let dashboardContent;

    // Loading state is always false (setAccountsLoading not being called properly)
    if (loading) {
      dashboardContent = <p>Loading...</p>;
    } else if (accounts === null || Object.keys(accounts).length === 0) {
      dashboardContent = (
        <div>
          <h4>
            <b>Welcome,</b> User
          </h4>
          <p className="flow-text grey-text text-darken-1">
            To get started, link your first bank account below
          </p>
          <PlaidLink
            clientName="Mosaic"
            className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3"
            env="sandbox"
            product={["auth", "transactions"]}
            publicKey="0c3ff69a2efea552189de8b7fbbc0f"
            onSuccess={this.handleOnSuccess}
            style={{
              width: "185px",
              letterSpacing: "1.5px",
              borderRadius: "3px",
              marginTop: "1rem"
            }}
          >
            Link Account
          </PlaidLink>
          <button
            style={{
              width: "185px",
              borderRadius: "3px",
              letterSpacing: "1.5px",
              marginTop: "1rem"
            }}
            onClick={this.onLogoutClick}
            className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable red accent-3"
          >
            Logout
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      dashboardContent = <Transactions accounts={accounts} />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 center-align">{dashboardContent}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getAccounts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  addAccount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  plaid: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  plaid: state.plaid
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser, getAccounts, addAccount }
)(Dashboard);
```

The loading value is always false (it is not being switched to true at any point). In my dashboard, if I `console.log(loading)`, I see two messages showing that `loading` is false (one when `getAccounts` is triggered and one when `getAccounts` is finished).

An (incorrect) workaround I'm currently using is to call the `setAccountsLoading` from within my component itself. When I do this, the loading value gets set to `true` until `getAccounts` is finished (which sets `loading` back to false).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PlaidLink from "react-plaid-link";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logoutUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import {
  getAccounts,
  setAccountsLoading,
  addAccount
} from "../../actions/accountActions";

import Transactions from "./Transactions";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAccounts();
    // Temporary workaround; this has the desired outcome
    this.props.setAccountsLoading();
  }

  // Logout
  onLogoutClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser();
  };

  // Add account
  handleOnSuccess = (token, metadata) => {
    const plaidData = {
      public_token: token,
      metadata: metadata
    };

    this.props.addAccount(plaidData);
  };

  render() {
    const { accounts, loading } = this.props.plaid;

    let dashboardContent;
    if (loading) {
      dashboardContent = <p>Loading...</p>;
    } else if (accounts === null || Object.keys(accounts).length === 0) {
      dashboardContent = (
        <div>
          <h4>
            <b>Welcome,</b> User
          </h4>
          <p className="flow-text grey-text text-darken-1">
            To get started, link your first bank account below
          </p>
          <PlaidLink
            clientName="Mosaic"
            className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3"
            env="sandbox"
            product={["auth", "transactions"]}
            publicKey="0c3ff69a2efea552189de8b7fbbc0f"
            onSuccess={this.handleOnSuccess}
            style={{
              width: "185px",
              letterSpacing: "1.5px",
              borderRadius: "3px",
              marginTop: "1rem"
            }}
          >
            Link Account
          </PlaidLink>
          <button
            style={{
              width: "185px",
              borderRadius: "3px",
              letterSpacing: "1.5px",
              marginTop: "1rem"
            }}
            onClick={this.onLogoutClick}
            className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable red accent-3"
          >
            Logout
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      dashboardContent = <Transactions accounts={accounts} />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 center-align">{dashboardContent}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getAccounts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  addAccount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  plaid: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  plaid: state.plaid
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser, getAccounts, setAccountsLoading, addAccount }
)(Dashboard);
```

Does anyone know why the `dispatch(setAccountsLoading)` in my `getAccounts` action is not properly updating the loading state?

Comment: just replace `dispatch(setAccountsLoading);` with `dispatch(setAccountsLoading());`

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that... that was indeed the issue. Thanks so much @VassilisPallas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Vassilis Pallas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3763848/vassilis-pallas) in a comment, the parentheses after the function call are missing, so you should have `dispatch(setAccountsLoading())` instead of `dispatch(setAccountsLoading)`.

In another topic, I would like to recommend [Redux Promise Middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware) to simplify using requests in Redux, you need only to dispatch the request promise as the payload, and this package will handle it for you, dispatching Pending, Fulfilled and Rejected actions depending on the resolution of the passed Promise.

This helped me simplify my asynchronous Redux code a lot, especially when paired with something like [Type to Reducer](https://github.com/tomatau/type-to-reducer), as suggested in the [reducers documentation of Redux Promise Middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware/blob/master/docs/guides/reducers.md).